# do you know how to modify the regex to allow one '-' char at the beginning of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

i have the existing regex pattern: `/^-?(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*$/`,

Currently the above regex do not allow - char at beginning of the string

Do you know how to modify the regex to also allow  one '-' input besides the above existing validation
My attempt:

```
/^(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*$/
```

but it doesn't work well.

Comment: `^-?(?!0\d|$)\d+\.?\d*$` to not match an empty string but allow only a `-` https://regex101.com/r/iSwm4V/1 or `^-?(?!0\d|$)\d+(?:\.\d+)?$` to match an optional decimal  part without a dot only at the end https://regex101.com/r/NQLZ3b/1

Comment: thanks but looks like there are a lot of modification on the existing regex. is there a minimal way of modifying it

Comment: [Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/pmGLaV/2) allows a `-` at the start.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/iSwm4V/4 does not allow a - at the start

Comment: This will `^(?!-?0\d|$)-?(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?$`  https://regex101.com/r/JLdW1i/1 or `^(?!-?0\d)-?(?:\d+\.?\d*)?$` https://regex101.com/r/3QnpFG/1

Comment: Thanks TheForthBird i would also want to allow 1. (one with a dot).
In the existing Regex, it does allow number with a dot

Comment: @user21 Did the answers work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the regex and accept only a `-` as well, you could make 2 optional parts, and assert that the string is not empty.

```
^(?!-?0\d|$)-?(?:\d+\.?\d*)?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!-?0\d|$)` Assert not optional `-` 0 and digit or end of string
- `-?` Match optional `-`
- `(?:\d+\.?\d*)?` Optionally match 1+ digits, optional . and 0+ digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M3FlWE/1)

Answer (score 0):

You first supplied regex: `/^-?(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*$/` does permit a leading - (minus sign)

Comment: thanks but if just - sign it will show error

Comment: example: would like to allow only '-' too

Comment: i know existing regex allow -3, but would also like to allow - too